# Refactoring exception code in java

Tags: java, exception, refactoring

I am working on code that should throw the same exception for two different things, and I don't want to use throws Exception with the method getIsbnNumber().

Is there any way of refactoring the code?

```
public void getIsbnNumber()
{
  try
  {
     value = new URN("urn:isbn:12345");
     if (value.getSecondElement() != "isbn")
     {
         //throws the urn same exception
     }
  }
  catch(URNException exception)
  {
      //throws the urn same exception
  }
  return value.getThirdElement(); // return 12345
}
```

Comment: I don't get the question. Do you mean you want to handle the exceptions thrown by `getIsbnNumber()` in another `catch` block ? And what is the real type of this exception ? Using the root class `Exception` seems bad in this case

Comment: Avoid using `Exception exception`, try to be more specific as possible when you throw an exception, example `FileNotFoundException exception`. And throwing the exception again without doing some logic is useless, you don't need that, just place `throws SomeException` on method's signature.

Comment: I wanted to throw a URNException, it is user defined exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is anything to fix here. This is something you can find a lot when working with IO, for example. This kind of code looks familiar ?

```
BufferedWriter bw = null;
try {
   bw = openWriter();
   doStuff();
} catch (IOException e) {
   handleError();
} finally {
   try {
       if (bw != null) bw.close();
   } catch (IOException e) { 
       // do nothing, or print stacktrace
   }
}
```

In the particular case of IO, you can use a nicer, and safer Java construct, which is the *try-with-resources* :

```
// this will close bw no matter what
try (BufferedWriter bw = openWriter()) {
   doStuff();
} catch (IOException e) {
   handleError();
}
```

If you are working with resources, make them `Closeable` or `AutoCloseable` and use this. Otherwise, you have no other option than the double *try-catch*. Give us more details for getting better answers.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, it doesn't make sense to throw an exception, catch it, and throw it again (unless there is something you want to do *before* re-throwing it - which doesn't seem to be the case here).

Simply throw it once and don't catch it:

```
public void getIsbnNumber() 
{
    value = new URN("urn:isbn:12345");
    if(value.getSecondElement() != "isbn")
    {
        //throws the same exception
    }
    return value.getThirdElement(); // return 12345
}
```

Comment: I think you need `throws SomeException` there on your method declaration.

Comment: @markspace depends, not if it's a runtime-exception.